# Add ASP.NET Razor Pages route convention to all razor pages in a folder with validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I would like to have a way to specify a route convention applied to all pages inside a specific folder along with route data parameter validation.

For example, if I have a folder **Pages/Movie** with **Actors** and **Financials** pages inside it. Then what I would like is to access pages **Actors** and **Financials** pages inside **Movie** folder using following URLs:

> ~/{movieName}/Actors
>
> ~/{movieName}/Financials

Additional to that, it would be great to be able to:

1. If **{movieName}** does not exist show Not Found page of some sort.
2. If movie with **{movieName}** exists, then create Movie class and if possible using dependency injection access it is inside my pages cshtml file same way DB context can be accessed.

Ideally it would be great to be able to expand it further using **~/{movieName}/Actors/{actorName}/Bio** and so on.

Comment: regarding dependency injection, do you have a variety of `Movie` classes or just one?

Comment: @AntonToshik I only have one `Movie` class.